# Use of "permission" in technical writing

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, programming, technical

In a request for proposal (RFP) I am attempting to edit the following sentence-fragment which isn't grammatically correct:

```
"...except for staff permissioned to update..."
```

My problem is with the word "permissioned." The correct english word is "permission" and it should probably read:

```
"except for staff with the permission to update..."
```

That doesn't seem correct for an RFP though.

Is there a better word or phrase to use that conveys the technical meaning of permissions for an IT system?

Comment: You can use allowed.

Comment: How about [authorised](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authorization)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. "Allowed" sounds weak, and, while I like "authorised," it's a bit too King-James-y.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by King-James-y. *Thou* and *Thine* are King-James-y. *Authorized* is a common and straightforward word with the specific meaning you are looking for. The word *authorization* is used specifically in the contexts of authentication and permissions in computer systems on [both](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/Conceptual/AuthenticationAndAuthorizationGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) [sides](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871) of the fence.

Comment: Thou arte correct.  I was referencing the UK-spelling ("authorised" vs. "authorized") which I like, but is a sticking-point for many of my readers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, I would argue that "staff with permissions to update" would work great in the context of a technical RFP. TrevorD's suggestion of "permitted" might be the proper way to say "permissioned" in common English, but in a technical document, the concept of "permissions" is usually not an abstract concept but a set of concrete entities ("I have permissions to create, update and delete objects X, Y and Z") often linked to objects like Access Control Lists.

So in this context, saying "staff with permissions to update" will clearly link this passage to the part where you specify permissions in your system.

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps [authorized](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/authorize)

> to give official permission for something to happen, or to give someone official permission to do something:

Answer (score 5):

The verb is *to permit*, so use *...except for staff **permitted** to update...*

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest

> …excluding staff appropriately provisioned to update…

Comment: You mean the ones with enough food and ammunition to make it all the way to Oregon?